# Debian: All commands gone as root user.

Tags: linux, debian

So today I logged on to my root server and the first thing that greets me is:

```
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

I switched to root and tried to run nano, no success. After some research I found out that all commands are gone except the most basic ones.
The last things I did was adding some lines to /etc/profile and /etc/environment. And I added a symbolic link to /usr/lib/grails or something. But I didn't notice any effect immediatly. As a normal user I still have all commands btw.

Comment: Sounds like whatever you changed in `/etc/profile` introduced some errors into the script.

Comment: Your `$PATH` variable is probably corrupt -- did you blow it out when you changed /etc/profile?

Comment: I only added some lines at the end, at least that is what I tried to do. Can someone post me the default /etc/profile?

Answer (score 4):

First make sure you do something such as:

```
export PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin"
```

to be able to execute anything at all.

Next make sure you fix your `/etc/profile` file as you appear to have a syntax error in it ... the error suggests it is an `if` or another expression involving a `[` operator.

It appears that your `/usr/bin/id` is missing. Is it on another partition that wasn't mounted, is mounted `noexec` or similar?

For anyone finding this later: it turns out after `/etc/environment` was malformed (didn't contain all needed lines) and thus the environment of `bash` before reading `/etc/profile` was already borked. From `man ssh`:

```
   /etc/environment
          This file is read into the environment at login (if
          it exists).  It can only contain empty lines,  com-
          ment  lines  (that  start with '#'), and assignment
          lines of the form name=value.  This  file  is  pro-
          cessed  in all environments (normal rsh/rlogin only
          process it on AIX and potentially some  other  sys-
          tems).   The  file should be writable only by root,
          and should be world-readable.
```

---

On a Debian (6.0.6) this was my default `/etc/profile`

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games"
fi

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ]; then
    PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

export PATH

umask 022
```

Comment: it's this line here: if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then  as the error suggest id is not found, but why?

Comment: @Chris: see my comment in my answer: "It appears that your /usr/bin/id is missing. Is it on another partition that wasn't mounted, is mounted noexec or similar?"

Comment: It's a virtual server so that's not possible, but it's there anyway.

Comment: @Chris: on Debian `nano` is `/usr/bin/nano`. Giving the absolute path should allow you to execute it at least ... also please do `ls -al /usr/bin/id` ... and sure it'd be possible inside a VM, too.

Comment: so /usr/bin/id is working, id alone not

Comment: @Chris: then obviously whatever shell you use doesn't default to `/bin` and `/usr/bin` before reading `/etc/profile` ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18190/discussion-between-0xc0000022l-and-chris)

Answer (score 0):

I failed to run an ant-script since the `env` variable pointing to the Java installation turned out to be empty.

I ran:

```
source /etc/profile
```

and then is was not empty anymore, so  maybe `/etc/profile` is not run properly? Have you tried this? (No, I am not an expert, but I can be lucky sometimes... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on Debian jessie (8.0).

The /etc/profile starts with the following:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH
```

So these lines set the path, but they begin by using the "id" command, which can't be found yet because PATH is not set!

Just specify the absolute path for id in the first line:

```
if [ "`/usr/bin/id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH
```